# Create an array of values based of the index of another array

Tags: php, arrays

I need help and was wondering if someone could help me out.

I have an array structured like below

```
$a = array(
   'lkfjdfoidjifjsdofjsd' => array(
       'id' => 1,
       'name' => 'Example'
    ),
    'idfjijeifjeifejijef' => array(
       'id' => 2,
       'name' => 'Example2'
    ),
       'idfjijeifjeifejijef' => array(
       'id' => 2,
       'name' => 'Example3'
    )
 )
```

I would like to create an array $twoName['name'] based off the above array by its id number 2. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: The array's structure is complicated for no reason

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($a as $a_value) {
     $newname = "array" . $a_value['id'];
     $$newname = $a_value['name'];
}
```

Will produce arrays with names `$array1, $array2` etc.

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. I need the new array to be something like $newname[{the id}] and assign all names to this array where id equals 2. So the data in the array should be $newname['id']  = array('Example2','Example3');